# Is there a Iosevka Term package available on Nixos?

Tags: kde, nixos, nix

Related to the following issue: https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka/issues/231

Is there a `Iosevka Term` width available in nixpkgs? I can only find `iosevka` and `iosevka-bin` via https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#iosevka

Comment: Can you explain it better? As far as I'm looking at, it is a "configurable" font. Maybe you need to set some options...

Answer (score 2):

Based on example configuration that I found [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/31294#issuecomment-457045667) this is what I added to my nix configuration:

```
  nixpkgs.config = {
    packageOverrides = super: let self = super.pkgs; in {
      iosevka-term = self.iosevka.override {
        set = "term";
        design = [
          "term" "v-l-italic" "v-i-italic" "v-g-singlestorey" "v-zero-dotted"
          "v-asterisk-high" "v-at-long" "v-brace-straight"
        ];
      };
    };
  };

  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    iosevka-term
  ];
```

Iosevka is suppose to be configurable font, so idea with iosevka nix package is to override parameters and create your own packages as needed.